# How to compile php in after installing php, apache and mysql severs?

Tags: server, php, lamp

I have installed all the necessary servers to work with php in Ubuntu..

But i don't know how to compile php in Linux.

My hostname is "blackparrot"
my user name is "red"

Pls tell or show me a way to compile php here

Comment: If you just installed PHP, Apache, and MySQL via LAMP, you don't need to compile PHP.  Is there a reason you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compile PHP if you already installed LAMP as PHP is run in the server itself, you need just to invoke the files in the proper place as @MustafaJF mention.

Simply open `nautilus` with administrative privileges by executing (in a terminal or by hitting Alt-F2 for the run program dialog), write `gksudo nautilus`, provide your password and go to the `/var/www` folder, over there simply drop your php files which you can access later by opening a web browser and pointing to the `http://localhost/foldername/yourphpfile.php` address.

Where `foldername` is the folder where the php files will reside and `yourphpfile.php` is the file containing your php code.

A good example to test if everything is running fine is the to create a file with the next contents inside:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

Let's name this file `phpinfo.php` and place it at the very root of `/var/www` folder, after which we'll invoke it via `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` and will result in something like this:

[image]

*Results may vary from case to case.*

Remember that `/var/www` is a protected place of which you will need administrative privileges each time you want to access the files for a change or something. But if you prefer, you can (at your own risk) change the location of your `/var/www` to a different place for testing purposes, which will suppose no risk at all if you do it just for testing purposes and have your server not exposed to the net. See [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/76961/9598) for a workaround to change the default location of your testing server.

Please inform if you are experiencing any issues.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a sub folder under your apache folder.

It is usually named `www`.

You put all your website files under that folder and call the site through the web browser.